# What is mathematical name for parameters returned by a maxwell fit in scipy python?

Tags: python, math, scipy

I am fitting an array with a maxwellian fit using the code below:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
maxwell = stats.maxwell
params = maxwell.fit(vmag, floc=0)

print params
(0, 110.99252206746627)
```

I think the first parameter tells me the left cut off location of the maxwellian. What does the second parameter tell me?

Thanks!

Comment: scale parameter that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it isn't said in the `maxwell` subset of `scipy.stats` it is described in the [`scipy.stats.rv_continuous`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit) as the scale parameter.